# Quickly toggling between Java versions in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8

I have two web-based applications that are very picky.  Both prefer Internet Explorer 8.  One site requires Java 6, while the other requires Java 7.

Is there a quick way to toggle between Java versions in Internet Explorer 8?  I need to make this as simple as possible for end users.  Possibly using desktop shortcuts for each application that set the JRE right then?  Possibly a plugin that lets you toggle version from a toolbar?

Comment: There is almost definitely a FAR easier method than this, but failing all else, I'd consider setting up VMs that differ only by the Java version. That is a horrible brute-force approach. But it would work. There MUST be a fairly easy way though. On Ubuntu, I'd make a command-line call and restart my browser to accomplish this.

Comment: @Doc I wonder if a similar approach could work with Windows, setting the system JRE prior to running Internet Explorer.  There's a GUI buried in the Control Panel, but doing it via command line would be feasible.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the setting for default JRE is buried somewhere in the Registry. I don't really use Windows much, so I'd have to dive in to find it myself.